# How to get text with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, url, text, beautifulsoup, get

I want to get an e-mail address from: http://www.ceice.gva.es/abc/i_guiadecentros/es/centro.asp?codi=46000110

I have tried the following code succesfully:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<tr>
          <td bgcolor="#EBEBEB"><div align="right"><span class="Estilo1">E-Correo:</span></div></td>
          <td bgcolor="#F4F4F4"><span class="Estilo1">secretaria@mjosefacampos.com</span></td>
          </tr>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
data = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('[bgcolor="#F4F4F4"]')]
print(data)
```

Output:

```
['secretaria@mjosefacampos.com']
```

The thing is I want to get it from the URL. I don't want to use the HTML.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to get the same from URL:

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<tr>
        <td bgcolor="#EBEBEB"><div align="right"><span class="Estilo1">E-Correo:</span></div></td>
        <td bgcolor="#F4F4F4"><span class="Estilo1">secretaria@mjosefacampos.com</span></td>
        </tr>
'''
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'http://www.myurl.com'
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text(), 'lxml')
    data = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('[bgcolor="#F4F4F4"]')]
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add the [`User-Agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) Header
2. Your CSS Selector is incorrect

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "http://www.ceice.gva.es/abc/i_guiadecentros/es/centro.asp?codi=46000110"
HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS).content, "lxml")

data = soup.select_one(".nivelCentro tr:contains('E-Correo:') [bgcolor='#F4F4F4'] span").text

print(data)
```

Output:

```
secretaria@mjosefacampos.com
```